# Implementing MobileIron SDK. Which HttpClient use?

Tags: android, mobileiron

I need to intagrate MobileIron SDK in Android app.
The app use Retrofit library.
But MobileIron documentation says:

> HTTP Redirect for HTTP Tunneling is not supported for the following
>   classes (which do support HTTP Tunnel)
>
> 1. java.net.HttpURLConnection
> 2. java.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
> 3. AndroidHttpClient

and

> HTTP Tunneling when using non-standard libraries such as the
>   following:
>
> 1. com.squareup.okhttp.HttpClient
> 2. Apache HttpClient library that has been repackaged under the
>      ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib package

How can I replace Retrofit in app, if documentation says, that I can not using HttpURLConnection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use MobileIron AppConnect 7.5.4 for your Retrofit library, since Retrofit library depends on OkHttp API.

> Supported APIs
>
> An AppConnect app can use HTTP/HTTPS tunneling only if the app
>   accesses the enterprise server using one of the following APIs:
>
> - java.net.HttpURLConnection
> - java.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
> - Android HttpClient
> - DefaultHTTPClient, using the standard Apache HttpClient library with the org.apache.http.package name
>
>   Note: HTTP/S tunneling is not supported with non-standard libraries such as the Apache HttpClient library repackaged under the
>     ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib package.
> - OkHttpClient
> - ModernHTTPClient in apps built with the Xamarin development platform.

Comment: Thanks for response! I have already used AsyncTasks) I think in the next app update I try to implement Retrofit.